# How to display items horizontally in a listbox control?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, stackpanel

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to the window phone 7 application. I have the following listbox control in my application

```
<ListBox Margin="0,355,70,205" Name="WeekSummaryListBox" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" Text="{Binding Amount}" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" Text="{Binding Currency}" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>                            
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

In the above listbox control items are displayed vertically. I want to display the items in a listbox control horizonatlly. So I am using the following code.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

but when I put the two textblock inside stackpanel it gives error. For this I am using the following code

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" Text="{Binding Amount}" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" Text="{Binding Currency}" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>                            
</StackPanel>
```

I am trying for the following code. In the following code I am getting error

```
<ListBox Margin="0,355,70,205" Name="WeekSummaryListBox" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" Text="{Binding Amount}" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" Text="{Binding Currency}" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

I am getting the error "Cannot explicitly modify children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl.ItemsControl geneartes child elements for Panel"

I am using the following function to display the data in the ListBox:

```
public void WeekSumValue(int TransactionType_ID)
{
    UserInterfaceManager UserInterfaceManagerObj = new UserInterfaceManager();
    List<UserInterfaceManager.TotalSummary> WeekSummary = new List<UserInterfaceManager.TotalSummary>();           
    ObservableCollection<AmountCurrency> WeekIncomeSumCollection = new ObservableCollection<AmountCurrency>();

    WeekSummary = UserInterfaceManagerObj.LoadWeekSum(SelectedButtonName, TransactionType_ID, selectedDate);

    foreach (UserInterfaceManager.TotalSummary vWeekSummary in WeekSummary)
    {
        WeekIncomeSumCollection.Add(new AmountCurrency(vWeekSummary.Amount, vWeekSummary.Currency));
    }

    if (WeekIncomeSumCollection.Count != 0 && SummaryCombobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        WeekSummaryListBox.ItemsSource = WeekIncomeSumCollection;
    }
    else if (WeekIncomeSumCollection.Count != 0 && SummaryCombobox.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        MonthSummaryListBox.ItemsSource = WeekIncomeSumCollection;
    }
    else
    {
        ObservableCollection<TextBlock> NoRecordsCollection = new ObservableCollection<TextBlock>();
        TextBlock NoRecordsTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        NoRecordsTextBlock.Text = "No record found";
        NoRecordsTextBlock.FontSize = 25;
        NoRecordsTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        NoRecordsCollection.Add(NoRecordsTextBlock);

        if (SummaryCombobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
            WeekSummaryListBox.ItemsSource = NoRecordsCollection;

        if (SummaryCombobox.SelectedIndex == 2)
            MonthSummaryListBox.ItemsSource = NoRecordsCollection;
    }
}
```

In the above function data is coming dynamically. There can be two, three or more records also there can be no record. I am binding this dynamic data to the textblocks which are inside the listbox

I am using the following class used in the above code

```
public class AmountCurrency
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public String Currency { get; set; }

    public AmountCurrency(int Amount, String Currency)
    {
        this.Amount = Amount;
        this.Currency = Currency;
    }
}
```

How should I put the above two textbock inside the listbox which will display the items horizonatlly ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Comment: If I had a Dollar (pound, euro, whatever) for every question I've seen that contains the statement "I got an error" without actually including what the error was, I reckon I could retire.

Comment: I have modified my questions & described the error which I am getting. Please see.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question but I still can't totally understand what you're doing. Can you please post a complete example (xaml & CS) to demonstrate what you're trying.

Comment: I have updated the question for the details you are required. Please see the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me like you've got the two text blocks inside the wrong part of the template.

These two text blocks should be in the `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, not in the `ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="300" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" Text="{Binding Amount}" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" Text="{Binding Currency}" Foreground="Orange"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If you want to understand how this control works, then start from a [working "basic" control which shows items](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-2-Getting-to-the-ListBoxItems-in-a-ListBox.aspx) and then look at adding the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to that working sample.

Comment: I tried for the above code also but it displays the records vertically. The record for the pair amount and currency is displayed in one row then for the next pair the records are displayed in the next row. I want to display all the pair of records in one row only

Answer (score 0):

Replace `DataContext="{Binding}"` with `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` that works for me.

Comment: This is also not working. I have modified my question. Please see.