# Silverlight 4 DataGrid How to make nested datagrid data display horizontally and not vertically

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a collection of objects that has a nested collection of objects . I want the nested collection in my datagrid to display inside a nested datagrid horizontally, if this is at all possible. Here are my classes:

```
public class Details
{
    public string Customer {get;set;}
    public List<Type> Types { get; set;}
}
public class Type
{
    public string typeId{get;set;}
}
```

Of course they are really ObservableCollections and I implement the INotifyPropertyChange, but this is just a quick skeleton of my classes to get the main point out there.

It would be nice if I could it to display like this:

```
  Details Customer      
                    Types[0] typeId    Types[1] typeId  ....    Types[n] typeId
```

I hope this make sense. Basically for the type I want the id displayed horizontally. So how could I get just the Types collection to display as columns and not rows? I essentially want to add another collection to Type and nest datagrids to that one, but those need not be horizontal, just this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The RowDetailsTemplate might work here:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <xzy />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

The `<xyz />` would be the part where you display your Types horizontally. Depending on your needs, you can either make a UserControl (create a `public IEnumerable<Type> Types { get; set; }`, bind your `Types` member to it and implement the display logic there), a StackPanel or a simple TextBlock where you concatenate your type-names.

Comment: Did you mean this to work something like Adding a Listbox into the template like this example shows to display a listbox horizonatally? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978407/how-to-display-items-horizontally-in-a-listbox-control